# How to prepare a water sample for photometry

Tags: water, spectrophotometry

The purpose of measuring N P K Ca Mg S is to determine the amount of material consumed by different types of plants in different periods.
The initial solution, which is prepared as a nutritious solution, includes highly accurate and measured doses of substances such as Potassium Nitrate, Magnesium Sulphate, Calcium Nitrate, Potassium Monophosphate, Ammonium Nitrate, and other materials that supply the micro-nutrients required by the plants.
The resulting solution is very clear and i use this solution to irrigate the plant
after 1 or 2 day i re-irrigate but it's done with deionized water
i can measure the runnoff water (drain water) of the pot for the amount of material available (such as NO3,PO4,K,Ca,Mg,SO4) with photometer because water is transparent

The problem occurs when the initial solution of humic acid and fulvic acid is added. In this case, the water released is very dark and it is not possible to use this water in photometry.
I have searched a lot, but the easiest way is to use photometer and chemical reagents to measure the concentration of the material.

my question is :
- how i can remove humic and fulvic acid from water without change in the amount of other materials or low changes (needed material is: N P K S Ca Mg)?
- or how i can measure N P K S Ca Mg in dark water with photometer?

detail:
error measuring up to 15% is acceptable

Comment: I simply cannot find a question in your post. Are you asking for different methods to measure those elements? Are you asking something about removing humic and fulvic acids? I suspect you have an interesting question, I just can't find it. Also, this is a confusing statement: "The resulting solution is very clear and after two to three days of water treatment, the water dissolved in the water (drainage water) can easily be measured by photometer." The water dissolved in the water? Anyway, I hope you will try to clarify so you can get an answer...good luck!

Comment: hi
sorry,i have described badly
my question is :
- how i can remove humic and fulvic acid from water without change in the amount of other materials or low changes (needed material is: N P K S Ca Mg)?
- or how i can measure N P K S Ca Mg in dark water with photometer?

detail:
error measuring up to 15% is acceptable